# How to define an extension function for any class that implements interface x and subclasses Y?

Tags: generics, kotlin, set-intersection

I want to define an extension function for any class that implements interface X and subclasses Y. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fun <T> T.doSomething() where T : View, T : Checkable { ... }
```

Thanks to Steven Schoen for sharing this on a slack community.